# Cursor loop is not working. Only taking last value in parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I created stored proc so that user can select multiple comma separated values into single parameter.

Here I am getting some problem in looping those values. here is the code

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Testing] @Databases varchar(4096)
AS Begin

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @cnt varchar(500)
    Declare @sql varchar(Max) = ''
    Declare @DB varchar(50)

    ;WITH MyCTE
        AS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitStringList] (@Databases))

    select * into #temp from MyCTE

    DECLARE tenant_cursor CURSOR FOR
        select * from #temp
        OPEN tenant_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM tenant_cursor INTO @cnt;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        select @DB = dbname from CountryLookup where dbName = @cnt
        if @sql  = ''
        Begin
            SET @sql = 'select C1, C2, C3 
                from ' + @DB + '.dbo.T1 
                inner join DB1.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
            '
        End
        Else
        Begin
            SET @sql = 'select C1, C2, C3 
                from ' + @DB + '.dbo.T1 
                inner join DB1.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
            '
        End
        FETCH NEXT FROM tenant_cursor INTO @cnt;
    END

    CLOSE tenant_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE tenant_cursor;

    Drop table #temp
    exec (@sql)

END
```

Now when I execute my proc like exec [dbo].[Testing] 'Usa,japan,France'

It is only giving me records for france.

Can some one help me where I am wrong.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend this approach, but if you look closely you'll see that you're never appending to @sql, merely assigning to it.

Change your else clause to `SET @sql = @sql + ...`.

Comment: Now when I am using this proc into my ssrs report , it doesn't give me records for multiple values.

Comment: Got the solution. Just wanted to make a little change in your method . If you do not want break in results then just do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can see some weird logic, like the `if @sql = ''`; but the cause of your error is simply that you are overwriting yor `@sql` variable, so when you execute it, it only returns values for the last country that the cursor retrieved.

Comment: I made the changes like you said. But in reports this stored proc is not working.

Any other change should I make in my proc to get records for multiple databases into one result.

Thanks